# Using addClass and removeClass on android like navigation drawer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the android style navigation drawer for my site. The code to the drawer can be found at [touch-menu-la](https://github.com/ericktatsui/Touch-Menu-Like-Android)

when I open the menu, the body content scrolls. which i didnt want. so i implemented the following CSS using javascript:

```
        var TouchMenu = TouchMenuLA({
            target: document.getElementById('menu'),
            onOpen: function() {
                $("body").addClass("noscroll");
            },
            onClose: function() {
                $("body").revmoveClass("noscroll");
            }
        });
```

what happens now is that the "noscroll" class does get implemented on the body when i open the menu, i.e. "addClass("noscroll")" works. but when i close the menu, the "noscroll" class is not removed, i.e. "removeClass("noscroll") doesnot work.

The "noscroll" class is defined as:

```
body.noscroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

How can I get the removeClass to work? Please advise!

Regards,
Aashish

Comment: revmoveClass ... just a typo error at onClose function

Comment: WOW! Thanks a ton @rafaelcastrocouto! I could have not gotten the mistake.. I guess i need a break before  continuing the onward development... Thanks a lot once again...

Comment: you are welcome, and relax ... it just happens.

Comment: ya... it does sometimes! ;P